# How do I get a file to read into an Arraylist, when the file is opened through a filechooser

Tags: java, arrays, file-handling

I am trying to get a file to read into an `Arraylist`, then take the numbers read from the file and calculate the average. I am having trouble getting it to read the file and I am opening with a `JFileChooser`. I have spent three days trying to get this to work. I have seen some similar questions on here but none using a `JFileChooser`.

Here is my code for the `JFileChooser`. I know how to calculate the average, but I just need to read the numbers in the file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Week07 {
    static JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String theFile;
        theFile = getTheFileName();
        double theAverage;
        theAverage = getTheAverage(theFile);
        displayTheResult(theAverage,"The average is: ");
    }
    public static String getTheFileName() { 
        String status;
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        status = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath(); {

            return status;
        }

        }

    private static double getTheAverage(String theFile) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
        String fileName = getTheFileName();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(theFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

so here is what i have, but now i cant get it to display the average.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Week07 {
    static JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String theFile;
        theFile = getTheFileName();
        double theAverage;
        //theAverage = getTheAverage(theFile);
        //displayTheResult(theAverage,"The average is: ");
    }
    public static String getTheFileName() { 
        String status;
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        status = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath(); {

            return status;
        }

        }

    public List<String> readFile() throws IOException
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        //check result
        File theFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

           //needs exception handling etc.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(theFile));
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
             data.add(line);

        br.close();
        return data;
    }}


public static double average(List<Integer> readFile) {

    if (readFile == null || readFile.isEmpty())
    return 0.0;
    // Calculate the summation of the elements in the list
    long sum = 0;
    int n = readFile.size();
    // Iterating manually is faster than using an enhanced for loop.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += readFile.get(i);
    // We don't want to perform an integer division, so the cast is mandatory.
    return ((double) sum) / n;

}
}
```

Comment: Where is the File reading code?

Comment: Two orthogonal problems. Whether the file is selected through a FileChooser does not matter.

Comment: here is the code with the file reading code.

Comment: private static double getTheAverage(String theFile) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
  String fileName = getTheFileName();
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(theFile);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

Answer (score 0):

In Java there is the `File` class which is used for dealing with, well files. So whether you get the file from a FileChooser or by any other means does not matter.

There are a few things I would do differently in your getTheFileName() methode:

- Return the `File` directly instead of the path
- Creating the `JFileChooser` inside the methode
- Check the return value of `showOpenDialog` (what if the user presses Cancel)

Here is some example code which reads the content of a file in a list of strings:

```
public List<String> readFile()
{
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    //check result
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

    //needs exception handling etc.
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
         data.add(line);

    br.close();
    return data;
}
```

If you are using >= Java 7 you can simply use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```
List<String> data = Files.readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs);
```

Another way would be to use the `Scanner` class. This would maybe simplify things, since you can directly check and read integer/double values and sum them up.

Comment: This is a good answer, except you're not handling your resources appropriately.  If some kind of exception is thrown, you won't close the `BufferedReader`.  I do like the reference to `Files.readAllLines` though

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the proper use of the `JFileChooser`...

`JFileChooser#showOpenDiaog` returns an `int`

> **Returns:**
>  the return state of the file chooser on popdown:
>  JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION
>   JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION
>  JFileChooser.ERROR_OPTION if an error
>   occurs or the dialog is dismissed

This is important, as `JFileChooser#getSelectedFile` may also return `null`, which would cause your current code...

```
public static String getTheFileName() { 
    String status;
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    status = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath(); {
        return status;
    }

}
```

To throw a `NullPointerException`...

Instead, you should consider using something like...

```
public static File getTheFileName() { 
    File file = null;
    if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    }
    return file;
}
```

The reason for using the actual `File` object is it carries much more context and functionality the just a `String` alone.

The next step is to read the file.  Depending on which version of Java you are using you could use...

```
File file = ...;

List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(25);
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

    String text = null;
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        values.add(text);
    }

} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

For Java 7 (using `try-with-resources`) or

```
File file = ...;

List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(25);
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));            
    String text = null;
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        values.add(text);
    }
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

If you are using Java 6 or earlier. The important thing here is to make sure you are properly closing your resources, if you open, you must make every effort to close it.

Check out [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and [How to use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details